# How can I fix the ImportError: No module named watchdog.observers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, import, pip

I want to use the watchdog module in python on my mac.
I already downloaded python3 via Homebrew. ( `$ which python3` results in `/usr/local/bin/python3` ; `$ which python` results in `/usr/bin/python`. )
After I installed homebrew, python3 and automatically pip3(because of homebrew), I typed in the command `$ pip3 install watchdog`. The installation of watchdog worked fine and when I type in `$ pip3 list`, watchdog is shown as an installed package. When I execute the following script on the other hand, I get an error which tells me, that watchdog.observer was not found.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
# pip install watchdog for these packages to work

import os
import json
import time

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
            src = folder_to_track + "/" + filename
            new_destination = folder_destination + "/" + filename
            os.rename(src, new_destination)

folder_to_track = "/Users/eve/Desktop/folder1"
folder_destinatiom = "/Users/eve/Desktop/folder2"
event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_to_track, recursive=True)

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eve/Desktop/auto_ideas.py", line 1, in <module>
    from watchdog.observers import Observer
ImportError: No module named watchdog.observers
```

In my programming environment, VS Code, I can execute the script either with `python 2.6.9. 64Bit, saved at /usr/bin/python2.6`or with `python 2.7.10 64Bit, saved at /usr/bin/python`or with `python 3.7.6 64Bit, saved at /usr/local/bin/python3`or lastly with `python 3.7.6 64Bit, saved at /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7`. Non of those options work for me - I get the same error, everytime I try. Does someone know, how I could make watchdogs work under these conditions? Thanks in advance

Comment: The script also is not called watchdog.py. It is called `auto_ideas.py`.

Comment: `ls $(python -c "import watchdog; print(watchdog.__path__[0])")` to find out if there is `observers/__init__.py`.

Comment: As I paste this into the terminal and execute it, I get the following output: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named watchdog
Applications  Library   Public Movies  Sites
Desktop   Music  
Documents  OneDrive
Downloads  Pictures` - seems like the import of watchdog itself doesn't work properly, not just watchdog.observer.

Comment: `pip3 show --files watchdog`

Comment: Ok, the summarized output is as follows:                                                                                                                                                                                            `Name: watchdog;
Version: 0.8.2;
Summary: Filesystem events monitoring;
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages;
Files: (there are way more) watchdog/events.py, watchdog/observers/__init__.py,  ...;  `

Comment: `python -c "import sys; print('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages' in sys.path)"` to test if the directory is used by Python. Test different Pythons.

Comment: The result is "False", for all python versions.. :(. The System one and the ones that were installed by homebrew

Comment: Quick and dirty fix: `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` in the shell or `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages python`. Not sure about real fix. I don't understand how comes the `pip` installs packages into a directory not in `sys.path`.

Comment: maybe you created file `watchdog.py` or subfolder `watchdog` and now it imports this file/folder instead of module `watchdog` and it can't find `watchdog.observers` in your file/folder. You could check `print(watchdog.__file__)` to see what file is loaded.

Comment: I can actually just find one folder, that is called "watchdog". But this folder is the directory to the installed module/package /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/watchdog. `print(watchdog.__file__)` results in the output: `NameError: name 'watchdog' is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem! I don't know why but running my script with python.exe path is working!

```
C:\Python37\python.exe c:\rw_projects\mtl_error_notifier\mtl_error_notifier.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in VS Code make sure you Manage Workspace Trust.

Hope this helped

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).